# Closest equivalent to kusto's make_list_if() / make_set_if() in Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am looking to collect all records with errors for each `CorrelationId`. In Kusto that looks like this:

```
logs_CL
| summarize
 Errors=make_list_if(Error, isnotempty(Error)), 
 by CorrelationId
```

When looking at AzureSql aggregate functions it seems none of those `make_list`/`make_set` families of commands are available https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Is there any way to aggregate the *contents*  of many records into one record? That is, we need to retain information from each record, not just compute a statistic applying to the entire set of records (such as min max stdev mean).

Comment: Show some sample data and desired results, rather than expect us to understand the workings of some other system and translate it to SQL server

Comment: `STRING_AGG` might be what you're looking for

Comment: @siggemannen  that's precisely what I need . care to make an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server version 2017+, you can use STRING_AGG aggregate function (see docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to concatenate info into a single column.

A very basic example:

```sql
SELECT TOP 30 so.name AS object
    , STRING_AGG(sc.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sc.column_id) AS columns
FROM sys.objects so
INNER JOIN sys.columns sc
    ON  sc.object_id = so.object_id
GROUP BY so.name;
```

This outputs some tables and their columns separated by ','

Comment: What took you so long?  :)